# ZF2 hydrating multiple rows into class's property that should be array

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF2, suppose I have a query result from the database like this:

```
Name | Value 
-----+-------
a    | 1
a    | 2
a    | 3
b    | 6
b    | 1
b    | 5
...
```

There is a class:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    protected $values;
    // + getter and setter for $values
}
```

I want to hydrate `SomeClass` so that I have the `values` property as an array, like [1, 2, 3].

How to do this?

PS: I know the hydration is done with the `HydratingResultSet()`, but AFAIK, `HydratingResultSet()` hydrates one object per table row, whereas here I need to hydrate 1 object for several rows.

EDIT: after remarks from @newage, understood that the question wasn't well described.

I need to have the objects, instantiated from `SomeClass`, like `a = new SomeClass()` and `b = new SomeClass()` that will have the `values` variables filled with `[1, 2, 3]` for `a`, and `[6, 1, 5]` for `b` -- exactly what corresponds to `a` and `b` from the database query result.

Comment: One object per table row is an entity. One object for several rows (entities) is a collection.

Comment: this doesn't really tell how to do what i need to do :-)

Comment: `HydratingResultSet()` will return a collection with hydrated entities. One entity = 1 row from DB.

Comment: You can use SQL way with `CONCAT` or PHP way with `foreach` and fill an object `SomeClass`. Hydrators don't help because you have more than one row for your class.

Comment: @newage, that's what i thought too. thanks anyway. please update your answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: What do you mean about update my answer ?

Comment: add info about `foreach` in your answer, and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `HydratingResultSet` will return a `ResultSet`. `ResultSet` implements `Iterator` interface. It return array of results.

If you need other collection class, you can write it.
For example:

```
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'); // Get an adapter
$hydrator = new ClassMethods; // Create a hydrator.
$entity = Entity\User::class; // Entity class name
$prototype = new EntityCollection($hydrator, $entity);
$table = new TableGateway('table_name', $dbAdapter, null, $prototype);
```

If your entity with methods `set...` and `get...`, you need use `ClassMethods` hydrator. If entity with properties, need use `ObjectProperty` hydrator.

For creating a collection of entities. Need create a collection class, it need implement `Iterator` and `ResultSetInterface`

```
class EntityCollection implements Iterator, ResultSetInterface
{
    protected $entities = [];

    protected $hydrator;

    protected $entityName;

    public function __construct($hydrator, $entityName)
    {
        $this->hydrator = $hydrator;
        $this->entityName = $entityName;
    }

    public function initialize($dataSource)
    {
        foreach ($dataSource as $dataRow) {
            $this->append($this->hydrator->hydrate((array)$dataRow, new $this->entityName()));
        }
    }

    public function append($entity)
    {
        array_push($this->entities, $entity);
        return $this;
    }

    /* Need create all methods from Iterator */
    ...
}
```

> UPDATE: after remark from @dima-dz.
>   You can read all data from DB and use `foreach`.

Like this. Example

```
$someObjectA = new SomeClass();
$someObjectB = new SomeClass();
$result = $table->select([]);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    switch ($row->Name) {
        case 'a':
            $someObjectA->add($row->Value);
            break;
        case 'b':
            $someObjectB->add($row->Value);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution won't create the array of values. i need the array.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, but i'm afraid i didn't explain well enough my question. sorry about that. updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

@newage, posted a great solution, but I found out there's another possibility to do what I wanted, maybe a bit simpler. There's a php function `parse_str()` that can parse a string from Mysql field and create an array for the `values` variable if you properly format the content of the mysql field. An example of a mysql `join` with the ZF2 that creates the needed string for parsing is like this

```
->join(
    ['t' => 'Table', 
    't.Id = t1.Id',
    [
        'Values' =>
            new Expression("GROUP_CONCAT(
                 DISTINCT CONCAT_WS('=', t1.Id, t1.Name) SEPARATOR '&')"
            ),
    ]
)
```